# How do I Implement Multiprocessing/Multithreading using Python in below code?

Tags: python, multithreading, twitter, multiprocessing

Below code block run for each Quarter of the year 2015. Each block of a quarter takes about 3 hours to run(so more than 12 hours for full code). I do not have much idea about How Multiprocessing works in Python.

As you can see All four tweets_Q1, tweets_Q2, tweet_Q3 and tweet_Q4 blocks run sequentially but they are independent of each other. I would like to run each tweets_Q1, tweets_Q2, tweet_Q3 and tweet_Q4 block on different process/thread. How can I achieve this?

```
def finalQuarterlyAnalysis(sorted_all_tweets,industryDictionary,startyear = 2015):
    resultDirectory = {}

    #sorted_all_tweets is a dictionary of ('Date of Tweet':'Tweet')
    #industryDictionary is a list of Training data set

    #Runs for the first quarter of the year2        
    tweets_Q1 = [(key,value) for key, value in sorted_all_tweets if key > str(startyear)+'-01-01' and key < str(startyear)+'-03-31']
    X1, vocab1 = createSparseMatrix(tweets_Q1)
    print 'Q1 tweets vectorized %d tweets. found %d terms.' % (X1.shape[0], X1.shape[1])
    Q1result = calculatePopularSectors(X1, vocab1, industryDictionary)
    resultDirectory['1stQuarter 2015'] = Q1result

    #Runs for the second quarter of the year
    tweets_Q2 = [(key,value) for key, value in sorted_all_tweets if key > str(startyear)+'-04-01' and key < str(startyear)+'-06-30']
    X2, vocab2 = createSparseMatrix(tweets_Q2)
    print 'Q2 tweets vectorized %d tweets. found %d terms.' % (X2.shape[0], X2.shape[1])
    Q2result = calculatePopularSectors(X2, vocab2, industryDictionary)
    resultDirectory['2ndQuarter 2015'] = Q2result

    #Runs for the third quarter of the year
    tweets_Q3 = [(key,value) for key, value in sorted_all_tweets if key > str(startyear)+'-07-01' and key < str(startyear)+'-09-30']
    X3, vocab3 = createSparseMatrix(tweets_Q3)
    print 'Q3 tweets vectorized %d tweets. found %d terms.' % (X3.shape[0], X3.shape[1])
    Q3result = calculatePopularSectors(X3, vocab3, industryDictionary)
    resultDirectory['3rdQuarter 2015'] = Q3result

    #Runs for the fourth quarter of the year
    tweets_Q4 = [(key,value) for key, value in sorted_all_tweets if key > str(startyear)+'-10-01' and key < str(startyear)+'-12-31']
    X4, vocab4 = createSparseMatrix(tweets_Q4)
    print 'Q1 tweets vectorized %d tweets. found %d terms.' % (X4.shape[0], X4.shape[1])
    Q4result = calculatePopularSectors(X4, vocab4, industryDictionary)
    resultDirectory['4thQuarter 2015'] = Q4result

    return resultDirectory

resultDirectory = finalQuarterlyAnalysis(sorted_all_tweets,industryDictionary,startyear = 2015)
```

Comment: You might be better off to segregate your 4 quarters in one pass rather than going through your data 4 times to construct tweets_Q1, 2, 3, 4. Then, maybe multithreading can help you, it is hard to say.

Comment: Even If I segregate all in a different pass, Python's powerful GIL(Global Interpreter Lock) doesn't allow me to work on different code same time. For ex. A code block of Q2 has to wait until the job of Q1 gets done.

Comment: OK, so maybe there's nothing to gain.